# Two constraint height conflict UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, constraints, height

I have UIView, which I have configured programmaticaly.
I tried to change height of MultiSelectsInputView (root view), but instead of changing I've got debug message:

```
MainApp[5765:768019] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28204d360 MainApp.MultiSelectsInputView:0x159c08830.height == 300   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820880a0 MainApp.MultiSelectsInputView:0x159c08830.height == 275   (active)>"
)
```

I'm setting constraints like this

```
 func constraintHeight(constant: CGFloat) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constant).isActive = true
 }
```

Why does it conflict with itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error you set the height twice - once with constant value 300 and again with value 275, and both of these are active simultaneously. These two constraints conflict with each other and so only one can be active at a time.

Looking at the code it appears that you have called `constraintHeight()` method twice with different values. If you need to change the height of your view, you should first deactivate older height constraint.

Keep a reference to height constraints, so that you can activate / deactivate them later.

```
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

heightConstraint = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constant)
// To activate or deactivate toggle the boolean isActive property
heightConstraint?.isActive = true // Activate height constraint
heightConstraint?.isActive = false // Deactivate height constraint
```